# Circular import error when importing weasyprint's HTML

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, weasyprint

I am trying to generate a pdf and I am getting the error below.

```html
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'tenderwiz.urls' does not appear to have any patterns
in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

The error occurs when I include this line in my view

```html
from weasyprint import HTML
```

**utils.py**

```html
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings
import os
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from weasyprint import HTML


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    html_template = render_to_string('invoice_render.html', context_dict)
    pdf_file = HTML(string=html_template).write_pdf()
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="invoice.pdf"'
    return response
```

**user_accounts/views.py**

```html
from .utils import render_to_pdf
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.contrib import auth
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from packages.models import Packages
from .forms import (CustomUserForm,
                    CompanyProfileForm,
                    CompanyProfileEditForm,
                    BankingDetailsForm,
                    PayFast_Form,
                    )
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from .models import CompanyProfile, OurDetails
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm, PasswordResetForm
from tender_details.models import Category, Keywords, Province
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus
import hashlib
from django.conf import settings

.
.
.
```

**tenderwiz/urls.py**

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from tenderwiz.views import privacy_policy_view, termsAndConditions_view
from homepage.views import province_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^user_accounts/', include('user_accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^about_us/', include('about_us.urls')),
    url(r'^contact_us/', include('contact_us.urls')),
    url(r'^pricing/', include('pricing.urls')),
    url(r'^privacy_policy/$', privacy_policy_view, name='privacy_policy'),
    url(r'^province/(?P<province_pk>\d+)/$', province_view, name='province'),
    url(r'^termsAndConditions/$', termsAndConditions_view, name='termsAndConditions')
]
```

**Traceback**

```html
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in
 url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, i
n wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserv
er.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 3
90, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 3
77, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 7
2, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, i
n check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, i
n _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, i
n __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Ayanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in
 url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'tenderwiz.urls' does not appear to have any patterns
in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the traceback, it will usually have the root cause of the exception

Comment: Added the traceback, check the question again.